# All possible calls to specific method

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a method that handle Checked Event over check box in c#, now i'd like to know all possible calls/invocations to this method from my system.

Note: I've tried making a break point in the first line of this method, but with this approach i must do like a monkey test (pressing all buttons, check boxes,...)

Any Possible solution other than noted one.

Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: Event handlers should always be private so this is trivial to figure out.  Of course, the ability to click the check box and thus fire your event handler is not.  Any program can do that.

Answer (score 1):

From Visual Studio: Position your cursor on the method name and hit Shift + F12 (or right click and select "Find Usages").